# Can I make sure that a function isn't called by others with the same params?

Tags: typescript, caching, typing

I wrote a little service that caches requests that return an observable. It looks like this:

```
export class CacheService {
  private readonly cacheMap = new Map<string, Observable<any>>();

  public cachify<T>(
    cacheKey: string,
    cacheableFunction: () => Observable<T>
  ): Observable<T> {
    const existingCacheItem = this.cacheMap.has(cacheKey);

    if (!existingCacheItem) {
      this.cacheMap.set(cacheKey, cacheableFunction().pipe(shareReplay()));
    }

    return this.cacheMap.get(cacheKey);
  }
}
```

Then I use it in the components like this:

```
  getNodes(): Observable<Node[]> {
    return this.cacheService.cachify('nodes|all', () =>
      this.http.get<Knotenpunkt[]>('/api/v1/node')
    );
  }

  getNodeById(id: number): Observable<Node> {
    return this.cacheService.cachify(`nodes|${id}`, () =>
      this.http.get<Knotenpunkt>('/api/v1/node/' + id)
    );
  }
```

Now the problem: It's possible that devs would use the same `cacheKey` twice (with a different intention!). This would be problematic because it would overwrite the cached stuff and thus provide the wrong values to the consuming functions. Is there any way that would allow me to control this?

I know that this is a "developer problem", would be nice to handle that in the service though.

Problem case in code:

```
this.cacheService.cachify('key-a', functionThatReturnsString);

// should work, because it's a new key
this.cacheService.cachify('key-b', functionThatReturnsNumber);

// should not work, because it's an already used key and returns a number (instead of a string like the first)
this.cacheService.cachify('key-a', functionThatReturnsNumber);
```

Comment: TS can't ensure this... You can design a different API, that allows you to ensure that there each function gets it's own unique id

Comment: Agree with @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. You could throw at runtime, but that's probably not what you want. Or if you can maintain references to the keys you're passing, then perhaps you could use Symbols? Symbols guarantee uniqueness even if constructed with the same string i.e Symbol('key-a') !== Symbol('key-a'). You'd need to maintain a reference to the symbol at the point you create it and then to retrieve it though

Comment: @mbdavis
Do I understand right, that I should return a symbol from the service and then store it in the component?

Comment: Yeah exactly. I can't comment if this is a good or bad approach from your example - but it may fit your needs :)

Comment: Sounds like a thing worth to try. Thanks!

Comment: You *could* try to use assertion functions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/PmL8vm), but it's fragile since as soon as you leave the scope where `cachify()` is called, any control flow analysis will be forgotten.

Comment: Or you could use a builder pattern like [this](https://tsplay.dev/DWKPKw) where calls to `cachify()` do not mutate the existing service but instead return a new one.  This might be clunky to use, but that clunkiness prevents cross-scope confusion.  Let me know if you want me to write up either of these as an answer.